# Best way to go about making application background fit different devices

Tags: android, image, layout, background

So I am looking to spice up my application a bit with some nice background images and such.  What I am curious about though is how do I make sure that different androids render correctly?  I will have backgrounds behind text and I need to make sure they are the same size and location for each different screen dimension and resolution?

Any good tutorials on this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

So I checked out the link provided on supporting multiple screens but I am still a little confused.

Say for instance I want to use a picture for the background.  On my device it would be 480x800, but what about the thunderbolt, droid x, moto droid, charge, etc.  Dont they all have slightly different screen sizes?

I know there is the ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xdpi folders so I can use 4 images, but what ratio will i make each one at?  Im sure they are not all 480x800 (and different densities)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create different images for different screen densities.

As you said, you have your dpi folders, each taking a differently sized image.  I used [this site which generates differently sized images for you](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-menu.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=example%5C) to figure out the different sizes that I would need.

Comment: but for a screen background, what dimension would i start with?  480x800?? and then convert to different densities?

Comment: You're right in that aspect ratio is not constant across devices. An original Motorola Droid uses a 480x854 screen, while the Nexus One, Nexus S, and others use 480x800. All of these are hdpi devices. 9-patches are a good way to address this. They are images specially formatted with regions that can stretch to fill additional space.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting site.! but i have one question. what about other widgets like TextView, EditText. when screen size is 4.0 TextView display well but after change the size like 5.1 then TextView is displaying smalll, what should i ? which technique i used?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) in the Dev Guide.

Answer (score 0):

If your background image is somewhat uniform in texture, consider using a single 9-patch image instead of using multiple images for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi.

Using 9-patch images also takes care of differing aspect-ratios for each of ldpi, mdpi, hdpi.